# PHP File Upload Keeps Timing Out

Tags: php, file, upload, timeout

I have an issue where I'm trying to use PHP to upload MP3 files to my site.

The connection / server times out after a handful of seconds.

This is the HTML code for the PHP upload form:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Upload Music</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<br />
<div class="center">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

And here is the uploader.php file:

```
<head>
<title>Success!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<div class="center">
<br />
<?php
set_time_limit(1000000);
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . 
    " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
file_put_contents("uploads.txt", basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']), 
FILE_APPEND);
?>
</div>

</html>
```

Here is my php.ini file:
`upload_max_filesize = 2000M`
`post_max_size = 2000M`
`memory_limit = 2000M`
`max_input_time = 1000000000`
`max_execution_time = 1000000000`

I checked phpinfo() and it looks like my php.ini file is being read correctly.
Is there any way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the folder where you're trying to store the images writable by the web server?

Comment: Yes I think. I can upload very small files but not several megabyte large MP3 files.

Comment: Web servers have their own limits too - what server and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using some variant of Unix with Apache 2.2.19.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the HTML comments in the uploader.php file. They're not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. My webhost doesn't let me upload files larger than 5MB... this kinda sucks but I guess I'll use external hosting.